# Calculate Page number based on two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below table I want to find the Page number.

The logic is if the sum of both col A and col b is greater than or equal to 15 then it should be page and it should be incremented.

Col A will be always 1 or 0. Only Col B will changed

Problem :

| Col X | Col y | col A | Col B | Pagenumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | 1 | 105 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 0 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 2 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 6 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 3 |  |
| null | y | 0 | 1 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 2 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 3 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 1 |  |
| x | y | 1 | 4 |  |

Expected output :

| Col X | Col y | col A | Col B | Pagenumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | y | 1 | 105 | Page 1 |
| x | y | 1 | 0 | Page 2 |
| x | y | 1 | 2 | Page 2 |
| x | y | 1 | 6 | Page 2 |
| x | y | 1 | 3 | Page 2 |
| null | y | 0 | 1 | Page 3 |
| x | y | 1 | 2 | Page 3 |
| x | y | 1 | 3 | Page 3 |
| x | y | 1 | 1 | Page 3 |
| x | y | 1 | 4 | Page 3 |

Query without pagenumber column:

```
SELECT 
    IIF(c2.isdeleted = 1 OR c2.approved = 0, NULL, c2.content) AS Content,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(c1.content, ', ')
     FROM comments c1
     WHERE c1.parentcommentid = c2.id
       AND c1.isdeleted = 0
       AND c1.approved = 1) ChildContent,
    IIF(c2.isdeleted = 1 OR c2.approved = 0, 0, 1) AS Contentcount,
    (SELECT COUNT(c1.content)
     FROM comments c1
     WHERE c1.parentcommentid = c2.id
       AND c1.isdeleted = 0
       AND c1.approved = 1) ChildContentcount
FROM 
    comments c2
WHERE  
    c2.discussionid = '402930'
    AND c2.parentcommentid IS NULL
    -- AND Content IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    c2.pinned DESC,
    c2.createddate
```

Comment: what is the ordering of records based on?

Comment: This is, unfortunately, likely to need recursion.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh which column you are referring.

Comment: They'll be referring to all of them, @devram . There's nothing in your data that we can use an `ORDER BY` on to retain the ordering your data is in. `ORDER BY ColX` would put the `NULL` first, `ORDER BY ColY` is pointless (as every value has the value `'y'` so achieves nothing), `ORDER BY ColA` would put the `0` first, and `ORDER BY ColB` would put the `105` *last* and `0` first.

Comment: I assume your question is about assigning page numbers to each row in the result set of the 'Query without pagenumber collum' [sic] - which _does_ have an `ORDER BY` clause FWIW. I would recommend to capture the query result in a temporary table, then use a cursor to scan through the rows from top to bottom, filling in the page numbers as you go. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the order of rows in which the cumulative sum should be calculated.

You can use a recursive CTE to calculate and partition the running sum.

```sql
with t(rn, x, y, a, b) as (
    select row_number() over (order by ???), -- set the ordering columns here
        x, y, a, b
    from your_table
),
cte(rn, x, y, a, b, running_sum, page) as (
    select t.rn, t.x, t.y, t.a, t.b, t.a + t.b, 1
    from t where rn = 1
    union all
    select t.rn, t.x, t.y, t.a, t.b, 
        t.a + t.b + case when cte.running_sum >= 15 then 0 else cte.running_sum end,
        case when cte.running_sum >= 15 then cte.page + 1 else cte.page end
    from cte join t on t.rn = cte.rn + 1
    where t.rn > 1
)
select *
from cte;
```

Result:

[image]